# Why is it necessary for database table id to be renamed to _id?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I created a new table in SQLite, and named one of the columns as `id`.

When I access that database at runtime, it generates an error. I found that in my database, I have to use `_id` instead of `id`. Why is it necessary for this column to be named as `_id`?

Comment: use orman framework https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman

Comment: It's not for sake of [reserved keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: @cularis: Please be more judicious when suggesting edits -- you waste our votes to reject your attempt to revert to something barely readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good idea to declare your primary key as:

```
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

That way, Android's functions, which could use the `_id` to make certain things work for example the id's in a `CursorAdapter`.

---

> For the primary key of the database you should always use the identifier "_id" as some of Android functions rely on this standard.

[From this source (direct quote)](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#overview_sqlightopenhelper)